# p5 Uncaught (in promise) Error when instantiating an object inside another class

Tags: javascript, class, p5.js

I keep getting an error pointing to a line where I create an instance of a class within another class.
`character = new Character(x, y, this.speed);`

The error says "sketch.js:33 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: character is not defined" which points to the line above.

Full error message

```
 `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: character is not defined
    at Stream.generateCharacters (sketch.js:33)
    at setup (sketch.js:11)
    at p5._setup (p5.js:63048)
    at p5._start (p5.js:62973)
    at new p5 (p5.js:63317)
    at _globalInit (p5.js:62466)`
```

Here is my code

```
let characterSize = 60;

function setup() {
    createCanvas (window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    background(0);
    stream = new Stream();
    stream.generateCharacters();
    textSize(characterSize);
}
  
function draw() {
    background(0);
    stream.render();
}


class Stream {
    constructor(){
        this.characters = [];
        this.totalCharacters = round(random(5,30));
        this.speed = random(5,20);
    }

    generateCharacters(){
        let y = 0;
        let x = width / 2; 
        for (let i = 0; i <= this.totalCharacters; i++){
            character = new Character(x, y, this.speed);
            character.setToRandomCharacter();
            this.characters.push(character);
            y -= characterSize;
        }
    }

    render(){
        this.characters.forEach(function(character) {
            fill(0,255,70);
            text(character.value, character.x, character.y);
            character.setToRandomCharacter();
            character.rain();
        });
    }
}


class Character {
    constructor(x, y, fall_speed){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.value;
        this.fall_speed = fall_speed;
        this.switchInterval = round(random(10,20));
    }

    setToRandomCharacter(){
        if (frameCount % this.switchInterval == 0){
            this.value  = String.fromCharCode(
                0x30A0 + round(random(0, 96))
            ); 
        }
    }

    rain(){
        this.y = (this.y >= height) ? 0 : this.y += this.fall_speed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the character variable before use. Change your code to:

```js
...
for (let i = 0; i <= this.totalCharacters; i++){
            let character = new Character(x, y, this.speed);
            character.setToRandomCharacter();
            this.characters.push(character);
            y -= characterSize;
        }
...
```